# Avoid GUI crash after user clicks GUI while a function is running?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pysimplegui

So, I have create a Simple GUI using **PySimpleGUI**, that upon a button click runs a script that moves the cursor left and right after specific interval of time. However, the script only stops when a user presses `Ctrl + 1`. Now when the script is running, if the user clicks on the GUI, the program goes to a **not responding** state. I want to avoid this. Below is a snippet code that explains my main code:

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def show_mainWindow():
    
    mainLayout = [
        [sg.Button("Start Script", size=(50,0))],
        [sg.Text("Press to Start"), sg.Button("Settings")]
    ]

    mainWindow = sg.Window("GUI", mainLayout, size=(290,75))

    delay = 0

    while True:
        event, values = mainWindow.read()
        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
            print("Close")
            break
        elif event == "Settings":
            delay = show_settingsWindow()
        if event == "Start Script":
            if delay == 0:
                mouse_thread = threading.Thread(target=keep_me_alive(6))
                mouse_thread.start()
            else:
                mouse_thread = threading.Thread(target=keep_me_alive(int(delay)))
                mouse_thread.start()

    mainWindow.close()

show_mainWindow()
```

Please note that the code for `keep_me_alive` is not posted because the script itself is fine, just in a `while True` loop until user presses `Ctrl + 1`.

Answer (score 1):

The value for argument `target` is a function, not the result of a function.

```py
class threading.Thread(group=None, target=None, name=None, args=(), kwargs={}, *, daemon=None)
```

```py
        if event == "Start Script":
            if delay == 0:
                mouse_thread = threading.Thread(target=keep_me_alive, args=(6,), daemon=True)
                mouse_thread.start()
            else:
                mouse_thread = threading.Thread(target=keep_me_alive, args=(int(delay),), daemon=True)
                mouse_thread.start()
```